# Laravel date comparasion not working for created_at column

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I've written a query for checking the messages that are written to conversation after it's deleted by a user that's in conversation. Here is my query:

```
$messages = DB::table('conversations')
                    ->where('conversations.id', $conversation->id)
                    ->join('messages', 'messages.conversation_id', '=', 'conversations.id')
                    ->join('deleted_conversations', 'deleted_conversations.conversation_id', '=', 'conversations.id')
                    ->where('messages.created_at', '>=', 'deleted_conversations.created_at')
                    ->orderBy('messages.created_at', 'desc')
                    ->select('messages.*')
                    ->get()
                    ->all();
```

But everytime i try to run this query with `where('messages.created_at, '<', 'deleted_conversations_created_at` statement if doesn't check for dates precisely. Why?

Here is migrations:

```
Schema::create('conversations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('sender_id');
            $table->integer('receiver_id');
            $table->enum('status', ['read', 'unread']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

 Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('conversation_id');
            $table->integer('sender_id');
            $table->string('message');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('deleted_conversations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('conversation_id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> deleted_conversations table

| id | conversation_id | user_id | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2021-02-28 11:26:36 | 2021-02-28 11:30:45 |

> conversations table

| id | sender_id | user_id | receiver_id | status | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | unread | 2021-02-28 11:07:09 | 2021-02-28 11:31:50 |

> messages table

| id | conversation_id | sender_id | message | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | S.A | 2021-02-28 00:00:00 | 2021-02-28 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | A.S | 2021-02-28 00:00:00 | 2021-02-28 00:00:00 |

Comment: Can you include sample data which demonstrates the problem?  Are you date columns text or actual dates?

Comment: I'll edit question. Date columns are created with `$table->timestamps()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to add a `where` clause where the value is another column, you need to use [whereColumn()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses):

```
->whereColumn('messages.created_at', '>=', 'deleted_conversations.created_at')
```