# Laravel. scope() in models with relation

Tags: php, laravel

user tabel

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 |
| 2 | test2 |

departments Table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | department 1 |
| 2 | department 2 |

departments_user Table

| user_id | department_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

Posts Table

| id | name | department_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | post 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | post 2 | 2 | 1 |

user.php

```
  class user extends Model{

   /**
    * @return mixed
    */
   public function departments(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class);
   }
}
```

department.php

```
  class Department extends Model
  {
   /**
    * @return mixed
    */
   public function users(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
   }
}
```

post.php

```
class Post extends Model
{
      /**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function departments()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Department::class,'department_id', 'id');
}
}
```

i need get all post from department user

i make Scope in post.php

```
/**
 * @param $query
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function scopePostsUser($query)
{
    $query->whereHas('departments', function ($user){
        $user->where('department_user.department_id',  'posts.department_id');
        $user->where('department_user.user_id',  auth()->id());
    });
}
```

my Query

```
Post::with('departments')->PostsUser();
```

error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'department_user.post_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where exists (select * from `departments` inner join `department_user` on `departments`.`id` = `department_user`.`department_id` where `posts`.`id` = `department_user`.`post_id` and `department_user`.`department_id` = posts.department_id and `department_user`.`user_id` = 3))

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: i want make the Query SELECT
 *
FROM
 `posts` 
WHERE
 EXISTS (
 SELECT
  * 
 FROM
  `departments`
  INNER JOIN `department_user` ON `departments`.`id` = `department_user`.`department_id` 
 WHERE
   `department_user`.`department_id` = posts.department_id 
 AND `department_user`.`user_id` = 3)

Comment: please explain the problem in the question

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66407559/laravel-date-comparasion-not-working-for-created-at-column/66407708#66407708 answer your question?

Comment: @Rwd no i do not want that  i want make scope PostsUser Right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all posts that belongs to all the departments of logged-in user. So to get the departments of logged-in user,

```
$departments = auth()->user()->departments;
```

Then to get all posts of those departments,

```
$posts = Post::with('departments')
    ->whereIn('department_id', $departments->pluck('id'))
    ->get();
```